# Laravel project stops building with Datatables.net build issue

Tags: laravel, heroku, npm, webpack, laravel-mix

I am working on a Laravel project hosted on Heroku. A few days ago, it stopped building and produced the following error message.

> ℹ Compiling Mix
> [webpack-cli] [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/tmp/src/js/vendors/plugins/datatables.init.js'] {
> errno: -2,
> code: 'ENOENT',
> syscall: 'open',
> path: '/tmp/src/js/vendors/plugins/datatables.init.js'
> }
> npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
> npm ERR! errno 2
> npm ERR! undefined postinstall: `npm run production`
> npm ERR! Exit status 2
> npm ERR!
> npm ERR! Failed at the undefined postinstall script.
> npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> ```
>    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>    npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.xfkpj/_logs/2021-11-10T16_57_33_522Z-debug.log
> ```

Any ideas?